Preparing to rebalance group dexterkafkagroup in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 535 (__consumer_offsets-25)
I am polling the messages from the kafka topic and it start rebalancing for around 30 mins and get stable after it. In kafka logs I am a getting
**Preparing to rebalance group dexterkafkagroup in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 535 (__consumer_offsets-25) (reason: Updating metadata for member sample-topic-76c8b44f8c-5k4z4-04f95075-2926-415f-a177-59f8061177b3 during CompletingRebalance) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-5] **
How to solve this rebalancing
